# Need a Optimised solution for Asp.Net Fileupload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have to store and retrieve the Image files .Can anyone please suggest me to save the file in the hosting system or In the DB. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Did you try searching SO for existing questions on this topic? What have you tried? What is your experience with that which you tried?

Comment: This question is also off-topic, because it's not really about the code, it's about whether to do X or Y. The duplicate I linked to has been closed for that very reason.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I searched in google but i am getting different answers . So I posted here to get clarification

Comment: The reason you're getting different answers is that *it cannot be once and for all answered*. It depends, on so many factors that the little information you've posted is not enough to base an answer on, let alone an *opinion* (which is also not wanted here). The question I linked to highlights a lot of the pitfalls, take that as an answer, it's the closest you'll get.